# Пост с картинками, используя markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

Создаю пост и внутри поста хочу использовать картинки.
Для загрузки изображений использую Paperclip.

Есть форма `new.haml`

```
.container
  %header
    %h1 Новая статья

  = simple_form_for @post do |f|

    %h5 Тема
    = f.input :theme,
      label: false

    %h5 Аннотация
    = f.input :annotate,
      label: false

    %h5 Основная картинка
    = f.file_field :main_image

    %h5 Текст статьи
    = f.input :text,
      label: false

    %h5 Изображения
    .illustrations
      = f.simple_fields_for :illustrations do |ill|
        .entry
          = ill.file_field :image
          %button.btn.btn-add{:type => "button", :id => "add_image"} 'Добавить еще картинку'    

    = f.submit 'Создать'
```

Из нее могу добавить к посту много картинок.

Вопрос в следующем: как прописать ссылку на картинку в тексте поста. Чтоб markdown ее разобрал.

P.S. Видел статью на эту тему, но там ссылаются на id картинки в таблице, но у меня же его еще нет. Как быть не знаю.

За раннее, спасибо.

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что вы хотите вставлять изображения в произвольную точку markdown-текста?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете.

Comment: Я бы тогда не стал цеплять изображения к модели поста, а хранил бы бы их в отдельной таблице - это позволяло бы сначала сохранить изображение, а потом воспользоваться ссылкой. Если вам важно учесть связи изображений с постом, лучше повесить на сохранение поста коллбэк - разобрать текст поста и установить связи после сохранения поста.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую реализовать на коллбэке!